# Multiple-reference foreign keys in table definition?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

### Summary

How do I make it easy for non-programmers to write a query such as the following?

```
select
    table_name.*
  , foreign_table_1.name
  , foreign_table_2.name
from
  table_name
left outer join foreign_table foreign_table_1 on foreign_table_1.id = foreign_1_id
left outer join foreign_table foreign_table_2 on foreign_table_2.id = foreign_1_id
;
```

### Context

I have a situation like this:

```
create table table_name (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null
  , foreign_key_1_id integer not null
  , foreign_key_2_id integer not null
  , some_other_column varchar(255) null
);

create table foreign_table (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null
  , name varchar(255) null
);
```

...in which both `foreign_key_1_id` and `foreign_key_2_id` reference `foreign_table`.  (Obviously, this is simplified and abstracted.)  To query and get the respective values, I might do something like this:

```
select
    table_name.*
  , foreign_table_1.name
  , foreign_table_2.name
from
  table_name
left outer join foreign_table foreign_table_1 on foreign_table_1.id = foreign_1_id
left outer join foreign_table foreign_table_2 on foreign_table_2.id = foreign_1_id
;
```

(That is, alias `foreign_table` in the join to link things up correctly.)  This works fine.  However, some of my clients want to use [SQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/) to query the tables.  This program uses the foreign key information to link up tables using a fairly straightforward interface ("Visual Query Builder").  For instance, the user can pick multiple tables and SQL Maestro will fill in the joins, like seen here:

[image: Visual Query Builder]
<sub>(source: [sqlmaestro.com](http://sqlmaestro.com/data/912/1183273856-250x238.png))</sub>

(That's a diagram from their website, just for illustration.)

This strategy works great as long as foreign keys only reference one table.  The multiple-reference situation seems to be confusing it because it gneerates SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
  table_name.some_other_column,
  foreign_table.name
FROM
  table_name
  INNER JOIN foreign_table ON (table_name.foreign_key_1_id = foreign_table.id)
  AND (table_name.foreign_key_2_id = foreign_table.id)
```

...because the foreign keys are defined as follows:

```
create table table_name (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null
  , foreign_key_1_id integer not null
  , foreign_key_2_id integer not null
  , some_other_column varchar(255) null

  ---------------------------
  -- The part that changed:
  ---------------------------
  , foreign key (foreign_key_1_id) references foreign_table(id)
  , foreign key (foreign_key_2_id) references foreign_table(id)
);

create table foreign_table (
    id integer primary key autoincrement not null
  , name varchar(255) not null
);
```

That's a problem because you only get 1 `foreign_table.name` value back, whereas there are often 2 separate values.

### Question

How would I go about defining foreign keys to handle this situation?  (Is it possible or does it make sense to do so?  I wouldn't think that it would make a big difference in constraint checking, so I've thought that that is a reason I can't find any information.)  My end goal is to make querying this information easy for my clients to do by themselves, and although this situation doesn't happen every day, it's time-consuming / frustrating to have to help people through it every time it comes up.

If there isn't a way of solving my foreign key problem this way, can you suggest any alternatives?  I already have some ways of getting people this information though views, but people often need to have more flexibility than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your definition is just fine, and SQL Maestro is incorrectly interpreting two foreign keys to the same table as the same foreign key, so I would alert them to that fact so that they can fix it.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  I couldn't tell if I was just missing something that would make it work magically or if it was something else.  Thanks.